# Creating a Bull's eye with for loops

Tags: java, swing, paint

So, i was reading my book and making exercises, it all went perfect until i had to do the first graphical exercise, i'll post the description of the exercise:

> Draw a “bull's eye”—a set of concentric rings in alternating black and
>   white colors. Your program should be composed of classes `BullsEye`, `BullsEyeComponent`, `BullsEyeViewer`.

This is my `BullsEye` class:
http://pastebin.com/4K7J2BM1

It's a tad long so i posted it on pastebin.

in case you need it, those are the BullsEyeComponent class and the BullsEyeViewer class:

```
    package GraphicalExecises;

    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;

    import javax.swing.JComponent;

    public class BullsEyeComponent extends JComponent {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            BullsEye bullsEye = new BullsEye(20, 10);

            bullsEye.draw(g2);
        }
    }
```

And

```
    package GraphicalExecises;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;


    public class BullsEyeViewer {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            BullsEyeComponent comp = new BullsEyeComponent();

            frame.setSize(200, 200);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.add(comp);
        } 
   }
```

Edit: So, it seems that i've forgotten to add the question\problem:

The problem is that it just draws the first circle and not the others.
I see that someone has responded with the recursive method, but i think it's a little too advanced for me.

Comment: and the question is what?

Comment: Please post your `BullsEye` and `BullsEyeComponent` class here.

Comment: So, basic idea. Know the number of circles you want to draw, know the area you have available to fill.  Start with the outer circle and work your way in...

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Do you _have_ to use loops?

Comment: No i don't have to use loops, i just thought that i had to, or that it was the best approach, since i'm only at the chapter 2 of the book.

Comment: See my **UPDATE** Below. Let me know if you can't figure it out. It seems kinda straight forward to me, since you I also have the recursive example that you can take from. I don't want to directly give you the answer. So work on it, and let me know if you have trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If loops *aren't* a requirement, you could look into using a [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) approach. Something like this method would work. Every time a circle is drawn, you subtract 5 from the radius until the radius is less than 5.

```
private void displayOvals(Graphics g, int radius, int centerx, int centery) {
    if (radius >= 5) {
        g.drawOval(centerx - radius, centery - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);

        displayOvals(g, radius - 5, centerx, centery);
    }
}
```

Here is an example

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class RecursiveCirclesPanel extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int radius = (int) (Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.9 / 2);
        int centerx = getWidth() / 2;
        int centery = getHeight() / 2;

        displayOvals(g, radius, centerx, centery);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }

    private void displayOvals(Graphics g, int radius, int centerx, int centery) {
        if (radius >= 5) {
            g.drawOval(centerx - radius, centery - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);

            displayOvals(g, radius - 5, centerx, centery);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new RecursiveCirclesPanel());
    }
}
```

---

### EDIT

What you want to do is have a `List` of `BullsEye` objects in your `BullsEyeComponent` class. Then just loop through them in the `paintComponent` method. What I would do, instead of just taking `x` and `y` arguments to the `BullEye` object, is instead to take the a `radius` argument. You can use that raidus in your draw method, doing some calculations on it to get the `x, y, width, and height`.

In your `BullsEyeComponent` you can add the `BullsEye` objects to the `List<BullsEye>`. Use a `while` loop, saying something like

```
while (radius >= 5 ) { 
    // add to the list a BullsEye (passing it the radius) and decrease the radius
}
```

This is pretty much the same as using the recursive method, but instead you make the recursion an iteration (loop)

**NOTE:** This is more of an OOP approach. You could do the same just using *one* `BullsEye` object, and while looping, decrease the radius and draw another circle in the `draw` method. So you have two options.

**HINT #1**

```
class BullsEye {
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2, int radius, int xCenter, int yCenter) {
        while (radius >= 5) {
            g2.drawOval(xCenter - radius, yCenter - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
            radius -= 15;
        }
    }
}
```

**HINT #2**

```
class BullsEyeComponent extends JComponent {
    BullsEye bullsEye = new BullsEye();

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        int radius = (int) (Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.9 / 2);
        int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
        int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
        bullsEye.draw(g2, radius, xCenter, yCenter);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know i'm missing something because i'm not a genius but...
Do i still need the draw method in the BullsEye class? because i think that's a requirement.

Comment: Yeah, I have the code already made up. I'll give it to you if you're throwing in the towel, but Let me give you some pointers about how I proceeded. 1) Yes I have a draw method (since that seems to be a requirement). In the draw method, I take a `Graphics`, `radius`, `xCenter`, `yCenter` as arguments. You can see in the recursion code above how those variables are used. 2) It the `draw` method I use a `while` loop, saying like "while the radius is greater than a certain number, draw a circle and decrease the radius" 3) In the `paintComponent` I calculate the `radius`, `xCenter`, `yCenter`

Comment: ... and create an instance of `BullsEye` then pass those values above to the `draw` method. You can also see above how I calculated the values.

Comment: I think i got it... ish.
So, i need the constructor to take radius, xCenter and yCenter as arguments and assign them a value and then pass them to the draw method, right?

Comment: Well the way I did it was not to take _any_ arguments at all, and just have the `draw` method take the arguments. I did this becuase, if you have the `BullsEye` take the arguements, then you would _have_ to create the `BullsEye` object on the `paintComponent` method, which is _never_ desired. So I just create a `BullsEye` object as a global class member object (not in the paintComponent), with no arguments. Then calculate the variables as I mentioned in the `paintComponent` method, then just call `bullseye.draw(...)` in the `paintComonent` method. The code above kinda draws it out.

Comment: Oh okay so the while loop is in the Component class.

Comment: Nope, its in the `BullsEye` class. Note: The code I produced uses only _one_ `BullsEye` class. You could do it the other way and use multiple `BullsEye` classes, but I wanted to stick to the way you were trying to do it at first.

Comment: My previous **EDIT** was kinda misleading. What I am explaining here is actually what's described in the little **NOTE** at the bottom of the **EDIT**. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I gotta go. Didn't want to leave you hanging so see the code at the bottom. Good Luck in your learning!

Comment: Ok i did it (actually you did it).
Just a question: is it actually possible to make a black center? i tried in some ways but it seems that i can't do it.

Comment: You had the right idea by setting the color. You can still do that in the loop. Also instead of the `while` you can also use a `for` loop, the way your were trying, so that you have a specified number of circles. And instead of drawOval use fillOval. Play with it :)

Comment: Oh and welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept answers that help you solve problems (the check mark :-)

Comment: So i had the right idea on the color setting? i'm not a complete idiot then!

Also, thanks for the help!